# When and where does Sinatra's request object exist?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm stumped I've tried everything I can think of to work around this and I got nothing.

When does Sinatra's request object start existing and where does it actually exist and how can I get to it from anywhere? i.e. another class that inherits from a class that inherits from a class that inherits from `Sinatra::Base` for example.

I've managed to get an idea of where it exists from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553091/sinatra-request-object) but I just can't seem get any further.
Things I've tried:

```
def self.request
   self.superclass.superclass.superclass.request
end
```

Various ways of changing the code execution context using `instance_eval or using:

```
def self.method_added method_name
  a = self.new.method(method_name)
    def self.define_method method_name do
      a.call
    end
end
```

and anything else I can think of but no matter what I do `request` is always nil, so I ask again, when and where does the request object come into existence during a request?

EDIT:

No offence but how is it hard to tell what I'm asking?

Here's the question, it's the in the title:

`When and where does Sinatra's request object exist?`

Sinatra has a request object, when does the object start to exist? (as in when is it not nil during the execution of code?)

When it does exist, where does it exist, within `Sinatra::Base` an instance of `Sinatra::Base` or within `Wrapper or some where else?

EDIT:

Here's what I'm doing:

in this example:

`r[:action]` is 'get'

`r[:url]` is '/'

`method` is `get_root`

`instance` is a variable storing `self.new` so I can access any instance methods.

```
            def method_added method
                return if Delegation::SIN_DSL[:basic].include?(method)
                r,p = get_r_data method
                m = self.instance.method(method)
                self.send r[:action], r[:url].first, (@options || {}) do         
                    (m.arity < 1 ) ?  m.call : m.call(*p)                                      
                end
                @options = nil

            end
```

Comment: I edited the question to show a few things I've done.

Comment: You get to it with the [`request` method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object). As for where it comes from, a look at the source shows that it’s an [attribute of `Sinatra::Base`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/9929353e6c59f07b8f6d98002778e0dc4a7faf3a/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L882) that is [initialised in `call!`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/9929353e6c59f07b8f6d98002778e0dc4a7faf3a/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L899) when the request reaches the app.

Comment: I've tried that but i just get `undefined method 'request' for Sinatra::Base:Class:`. When I do the same thing but instead of reuqest I do `instance_variables.inspect` I get `[:@conditions, :@routes, :@filters, :@errors, :@middleware, :@prototype, :@extensions, :@templates]`.I access it by storing a reference to `Sinatra::Base` and then accessing that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Inside your request handling code (routes, helpers etc.) you can just call `request`. Outside the request handling code there is no request to get.

Comment: Check my question, I added it in, also the request method is an instance method so it won't be an attribute of `Sinatra::Base` but an attribute of an instance of `Sinatra::Base`, there is a difference. I think the real question is where does this instance get stored? If I find that I can access its methods and the request object. Juding from the code it gets stored inside of `Sinatra::Wrapper` but then, where does that get stored?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sinatra app is a rack app. If you have

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
end
```

then where the `MyApp` class gets instantiated depends on how you start up a webserver that runs it; generally speaking the rack handler (which may be of different types depending on the http server you're using) will store an instance of the sinatra app. When a rack request comes in, the server or another rack app will `call` the app instance with the rack env hash. `Sinatra::Base#call` will then do [`dup.call!(env)`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L885), meaning that a shallow copy of the existing instance is made and then `call!` is invoked on the copy. The [body of `call!`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L889) is where the request object is initialized:

```
def call!(env) # :nodoc:
  @env      = env
  @request  = Request.new(env)
```

and it's this duped app's `request` accessor for this instance variable that you're typically invoking when you refer to `request` in a route handler.

Not sure if that helps you, but it should at least answer the question.

WARNING: Answer valid for sinatra v1.4.5, but you should not expect it to remain valid. These implementation details are not part of the public sinatra API and are not documented for a reason -- you're not intended to mess with it, and doing so will quite possibly break your app if you upgrade sinatra versions. I don't recommend writing code that depends on these details.